# compiz huge CPU usage while play Audacious

Tags: compiz, audacious

I have

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

and i can't use Audacious 3.2.1 (Ubuntu package), because compiz start use 25-50% my CPU usage. Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 350  @ 2.27GHz

Kernel 3.2.0-24-generic x86_64

VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M]

Compiz 0.9.7.8

I reinstalled audacious, but that not helps me. What to do?

Comment: a bug has been reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audacious/+bug/261509

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with cpu usage because of compiz. My workaround was to switch session from Ubuntu to Ubuntu 2D.

[image: ubuntu 2d]

Comment: Why down-voted?